# is there a way to find the average between certain consecutive rows?

Tags: python

I have a list of values that looks as follow:

```
first column  second column
140           1           
140           20
160           22 
200           50
200           60
```

I want my program to search on every row if the value of the second column is within a radius of 10 points from the previous or next row, if it isn't, then return the value of the row on a new matrix, but if it is then return the average of the aforementioned rows to get something similar to this:

```
first column  second column
140           1
150           21
200           55
```

I know this can be done on python with the help of numpy using a for loop to iterate on the list, and then use if/else statements to see if a certain row is within the 10 points radius but I feel it takes too many coding lines and wanted to know if it can somehow be shortened or be done in a more practical way. Here is my code:

```
for a in enumerate(first_list):
 if a < len(first_list):
  if a == first_list[0,1] and (first_list[a,1] + 10) > first_list[a+1,1]:
   secondlist.append([int(np.mean((first_list[a, 0], first_list[a+1, 0]))), int(np.mean((first_list[a, 1], first_list[a+1, 1])))])
  elif (first_list[a,1] + 10) > first_list[a+1,1] or (first_list[a, 1] - 10) < first_list[a-1, 1]:
   if (first_list[a,1] + 10) > first_list[a+1,1] and (first_list[a, 1] - 10) < first_list[a-1, 1]:
    secondlist.append([int(np.mean((first_list[a, 0], first_list[a+1, 0], first_list[a-1, 0]))), int(np.mean((first_list[a, 1], first_list[a+1, 1], first_list[a-1, 1])))])
   elif (first_list[a,1] + 10) > first_list[a+1,1]:
    secondlist.append([int(np.mean((first_list[a, 0], first_list[a+1, 0]))), int(np.mean((first_list[a, 1], first_list[a+1, 1])))])
   else:
    secondlist.append([int(np.mean((first_list[a, 0], first_list[a-1, 0]))), int(np.mean((first_list[a, 1], first_list[a-1, 1])))])
  else:
   secondlist.append([first_list[a,0], first_list[a,1]])
 else:
  secondlist.append([first_list[a,0], first_list[a,1]])
```

Comment: What would you do if you had a row like `[180, 31]` after the `[160, 22]` row?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi you will get a new row on the second list with the value [170,  26] right in the middle between the second and third (last) row.

Answer (score 0):

Is this any use to you? Don't know if you've saved any lines in your code, but to me anyway it looks easier to read:

```
import numpy

list1 = [[140,140,160,200,200],[1,20,22,50,60]]
list3 = []  #The output list of averages

for i1 in range(0, len(list1[0])):
    list2 = list1[1][max(i1-1,0):min(i1+2, len(list1[1]))]
    
    temp = []
    for i in range(min(1, len(list2)-1),min(3, len(list2))):        
        if abs(list2[i]-list2[i-1]) <=10:
            if list2[i-1] not in temp:
                temp.append(list2[i-1])
            if list2[i] not in temp:
                temp.append(list2[i])
    if temp:
        avg = numpy.mean(temp)
    else:
        avg = 0
    
    list3.append(avg)
```